# JQuery Mobile and CSS3 media queries

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I am writing a mobile friendly webpage and am JQuery Mobile. However, in my CSS I am using a number of media queries. This is all well and good except if I want to load a page using AJAX ( JQueryMobile's 'data-ajax' attribute). If I do this it doesn't appear that the media queries are being taken into account. It is only if I refresh the page that the media queries appear to kick in.

Has anyone had any experience in this respect or can they shed any light on my this is happening?

I have posted a sample on azure here to demonstrate. It comprises a login form (no username or password required - just click "Sign In"). On the target (home.html) there is a div that should be hidden using media queries for widths greater than 767px). However its not hidden when I resize down the window. It only happens if I reload the page and resize.

See here: http://testjquerymob.azurewebsites.net/index.html

Thanks in advance.

T

Comment: where are you referring the css files in the page brought in through ajax?

Comment: If you prove a test or more information you might get better help. Your problem doesn't sound like anything I have encountered and appears you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: @hungerpain - the css for the media query is actually stored directly in the page that is brought through with ajax.

Comment: @Ryan - see edit above for a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!

Very silly mistake on my side. As I mentioned above in response to *hungerpain* I was including the CSS for the media query inside `<style>` tags. I got to this point after moving them from an included stylesheet thinking that it would sort the issue. As it turns out it didn't. However, what I am after discovering is that it is within the loading page (page into which I am loading the destination URL) that I should have been either referencing the included stylesheet or at the very least adding the media query within the `<style>` tags.

So, to summarize -

1. I loaded index.html
2. I wanted to load *home.html* into it and hide a DIV in *home.html* depending on the viewport size.
3. Instead of including the media query in the *home.html* as I was doing I should have included the media query/stylesheet in the parent page - *index.html* as it is into that page that the html content of *home.html* will be loaded

Thanks guys,

T